# PyQt5 designer: scroll area layout menu dimmed

Tags: pyqt5

I am trying to add a grid layout to the scroll area in the PyQt5 designer, but the menu is dimmed and I can't figure out how to do it.

[image: Lay out menu greyed out]

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image: This is what I'm trying to do]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty container widgets cannot have a layout in Designer, and at least *one* widget must be added in order to set a layout manager.

If you want to set a main layout for a widget, add a child widget to that, then right click on an empty area of the container and select the proper layout from the "Lay out" menu.

If you want to create a layout but you still want that container to be empty (because widgets will be dynamically added by code), then just do the same and remove the previously added child widget.

Note that you should not add layouts from the widget box, as those layouts are intended for nested layouts: when you need to add an inner layout to an *existing* layout.

Also note that you must do the same also for the central widget, otherwise the scroll area won't be resized whenever the main window is. Always check in the object inspector if any widget has the small red  sign, which means that the widget has no layout set.

See the documentation about [Using Layouts in Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).